# Changing CSS based on variable

Tags: css, asp-classic

In ASP I wish to pass in a variable and based on that variable use different external CSS sheets. Is there a way to do this since it seems passing in a variable is done in the Body and caling in external style sheet is done in the header. Thanks.

Comment: Classic ASP is a "server-side" technology. This means that it can manipulate any part of the HTTP request before it is returned to the client, including the HTML head section. What have you tried so far? Any request for help should be accompanied by some code to show the OP has attempted to find a solution instead of just coming here and posting for help.

Comment: The other obvious question to ask here is: are we talking about '**Classic ASP**' or '**ASP.NET**'?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check for the variable in the header, then include the css files based on that.

```
select case request("Style")
    case "one"
    %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/one.css" type="text/css" />
    <%
    case "two"
    %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/two.css" type="text/css" />
    <%
    case else
    %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
    <%
end select
```

I occasionally include css includes within the body too - it's dirty but works in all modern browsers.